# Memory leak using ARC in NSData framework

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

i can't figure out one memory leak. I will add screen shot with code and marked line where this happens.

[image]

Maybe some could help me and take a look.

Thanks.

```
- (AVAudioPlayer*)getSpeachSoundObject{

    NSString *objectIDString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", jmObject.objectID];
    NSString * __weak textPlaySource = [DataController getMediaUrlStringForObjectID:objectIDString parentType:PARENT_TYPE_ITEM_AUDIO];
    NSError * error = nil ;

    if (textPlaySource) {

        //NSURL *soundURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:textPlaySource];//[NSURL fileURLWithPath:textPlaySource];
        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:textPlaySource options:NSDataReadingMapped error:&error ] ;
        textPlaySource = nil;

        NSError *error;

        //speechSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
        AVAudioPlayer *lspeechSound = data ? [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&error ] : nil ;

        data = nil;

        if (error) {
            WLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error creating sound file:%@", error]);
        }

        return lspeechSound;
        //soundURL = nil;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Do you properly cleanup `speechSound`?

Comment: How to properly clean it if i am using ARC ?

Comment: If you are using ARC then it may already be done properly but without seeing more of the relevant code, it's impossible to know if you are doing it right.

Comment: So this could occur anywhere in the class ?

Comment: The `data` variable is local to this block and appears to be cleaned up properly despite the leak. However, `data` is used by the `speechSound` variable. So the leak could possibly be related to that variable. You need to make sure it is properly dealt with.

Comment: I updated my question with method i use and memory leak is NSData line.

Comment: That's not the same code from the screenshot. Anyway, you return the `lspeechSound` variable so you need to look at how the return value is handled.

Comment: Yes i changed code to make AVAudioPlayer local, but problem still the same. I can't understand how this object could be treated that a leaks exists. Maybe i need to convert this class without ARC i every object to release myself